# Docker + MySQL 8: connection issues

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

MySQL in Docker won't connect.

I already looked into other posts but I can't find what I am doing wrong. Using MySQL 5.6 it connects fine. But I want to use MySQL 8.

This an excerpt of my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '2'

# ...other services and...

  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:8.0
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "the_database"
      MYSQL_USER: "my_user"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "some_password_123"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "some_root_password123"
    volumes:
      - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./data/mysql-dumps:/var/mysql-dumps
     # Tried this command to use mysql_native_password but still cant log in
    command:
      - "--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"
```

I can go into the container and try to login:

```sh
$ docker container exec -it mysql /bin/bash

$ root@7b4d6ada50fb:/# mysql -h localhost -u my_user -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'my_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
root@7b4d6ada50fb:/#
```

I'm **very sure** the password is being correctly inserted. But with no success. See that I'm trying to connect even INSIDE the container. And the ports are "bind" 3306:3306. Can't find anything else to check it. Any help is very appreciated.

When run my `docker container inspect mysql` these are some excerpts:

```sh
"Env": [
  "MYSQL_DATABASE=the_database",
  "MYSQL_USER=my_user",
  "MYSQL_PASSWORD=some_password_123",
  "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=some_root_password123",
  "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
  "GOSU_VERSION=1.12",
  "MYSQL_MAJOR=8.0",
  "MYSQL_VERSION=8.0.19-1debian10"
],

# ... and network:
 "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "873ee1fe38431b8b2c2a55e3b7c1b1649e14c5c8946c00e65820be72a0ff5b73",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "3306/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "3306"
                    }
                ],
                "33060/tcp": null
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/873ee1fe3843",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "project_default": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "mysql",
                        "7b4d6ada50fb"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "2f6e5947d747fb8518628361660193bce331efe2d79ce86e3e7f5cacf81ce26a",
                    "EndpointID": "8bc41562ce39de01cd4162cc5c9b9cb42b1a4f8eed8af884a31766b64eda8199",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.18.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I got what it was doing.

docker-compose create its own network. So, using the Network result from inspect, as I post in my question above:

```sh
"Networks": {
  "project_default": {
    "IPAMConfig": null,
    "Links": null,
    "Aliases": [
      "mysql",          <- HERE!!
      "7b4d6ada50fb"
    ],
```

I decided to try that alias in the string connection like this:

```sh
mysql -h mysql -u my_user -p
```

And great! I could connect to the container! This is probably because the comparison MySQL does related to the user and the hosts each user can or cannot access. But I'm not completely sure about it.

I'm thankful for any additional information anyone can provide.

And, since I'm using Laravel, I did the same in my `.env` file as well:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql   <- HERE!!
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=your_db_name
DB_USERNAME=your_user
DB_PASSWORD=your_password
```